# Trigger jQuery with form_for in Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new in Ruby on Rails and I'm trying to make to `form_for` trigger a jQuery function.

My code for the form is the next:

```
<%= form_for @company, :url => create_paying_registration_path(:industry => apt(@plan.industry, :industries), :plan => @plan.name),
    :html => {:id => "card-form"} do |f| %>
    <%= render 'form_carrier', :company => @company, :plan => @plan, :f => f %>
<% end %>
```

And jQuery:

```
jQuery ($) ->
$("#card-form").submit ->
$form = $(this)
$form.find("button").prop "disabled", true
Conekta.token.create tokenParams, conektaSuccessResponseHandler, conektaErrorResponseHandler
false
return
```

The form doesn't trigger the jQuery function but if I use a `form_tag`, it triggers the jQuery function:

```
<%= form_tag('/checkouts/charge', id: 'card-form') do %>
```

My question is, what am I doing wrong with `form_for`?
I need to trigger the jQuery and then redirect to the path from form.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For me, the used jquery syntax looks strange. However, does your jquery code work if you apply this on a plain html form, as local example test?

Comment: Sorry, I forget to mention that jQuery is writen in `coffeescript` the code works when I use the form_tag and plain html form but doesn't work with the form_for

Comment: Have you tried to use onSubmit with form_for?

Answer (score 0):

Add onSubmit to form_for

```
form_for @paintings, :url => "/paintings/handlelike", :method => "post", :remote => true, :html => {:id => "submit_form_id",:onsubmit => "yourFunction();", :name => 'form'} do |f|
```

And in your js:

```
yourFunction() {
 $form = ...
...
}
```